# RoR plugin/gem for html validation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am wondering if there is such a plugin or gem for Ruby on Rails that includes HTML validation (SGML or Tidy) in a testing cycle.

I am aware only about [this plugin](http://github.com/peter/html_test). Looking for alternatives...

Comment: would XML validation also do?

Comment: Yes, I guess that XML validation is fine too. I just want to be sure that my app looks more or less the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [`be_valid_asset`](http://github.com/unboxed/be_valid_asset) with rspec and cucumber. It uses the public W3C validator. It does not have the link checking that `html_test` has.

I use it in these two steps in cucumber's webrat_steps.rb:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
  response.should be_valid_xhtml if ENV['VALIDATE_HTML']
end

When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
  response.should be_valid_xhtml if ENV['VALIDATE_HTML']
end
```

Then I can run `rake VALIDATE_HTML=1 cucumber` to validate all pages visited by my cucumber feature files.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.
It worked well for me.
And I like your trick with env variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Rack-based validator that can be used live: http://coderack.org/users/nerdEd/entries/95-rackvalidate

Comment: Link is dead (or no longer working)

Comment: Try https://github.com/nerdEd/rack-validate

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an all-in-one HTML/CSS validation gem for Ruby On Rails apps. It's name is [Headhunter](https://github.com/jmuheim/headhunter).

From the docs:

> Headhunter is an HTML and CSS validation tool that injects itself into your Rails feature tests and automagically checks all your generated HTML and CSS for validity.
>
> In addition, it also looks out for unused (and therefore superfluous) CSS selectors.

All you have to do is add `gem 'headhunter'` to your Gemfile in test environment:

```
group :test do
  gem 'headhunter'
end
```

The rest is all done automagically for you, and you'll get a statistic for your application's validness at the end of your tests, like this:

```
Validated 42 HTML pages.
41 pages are valid.
1 page is invalid.
Open .validation/results.html to view full results.

Validated 1 stylesheets.
1 stylesheet is invalid.
  application.css:
  - Invalid css: line 1: Property bla doesn't exist

Found 23 CSS selectors.
20 selectors are in use.
3 selectors are not in use: a img, #flash.failure, input[type='file']
```